# Application object is getting modified when retrieved object is modified

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching

I am keeping an global object in application cache, retrieving and modifying it based on my needs.  The weird thing is once I modify the retrieved object the application object is getting modified too. I don't want the application object to be modified.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["obj2"]=obj2;
```

like

```
object obj1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["obj2"];
```

when I modify obj1 the obj2 is getting modified too.  Can you guys suggest me the solution for the above problem?

Comment: Consider cloning the object when you retrieve it.  What kind of object are you storing in the application?

Comment: You are storing an instance of a class in your application cache.  Assigning that instance to a variable doesn't make a copy of the instance.  It *is* the instance.  This is correct and expected behavior.

Comment: Back to the basics: [reference vs value type in .NET](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) before doing ASP.NET.

Comment: Inuyasha  could you suggest me the possible solution which will work to my requirements

Comment: You haven't given any requirements.  What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in C# are always by-reference, which means that whenever you access this object it will always be the same instance to the object. It sounds like what you might want to do is to clone it first then modify the clone instead. This is also important for shared memory multi-threaded environments like what you have above.

Also, you might consider making the object that you are caching a struct, which is passed by-value instead of by-reference, as long as you unbox it first. In general you don't want to edit objects shared by threads.